# progressbar doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript

I made a circular progressbar for my office work time. It also shows a time interval for lunch time. On fridays our work time is shorter by 1 hour. And the problem is on fridays the lunch time interval is placed wrong on the progressbar. It's closer to the end of worktime than it should be. Here's the code:

```js
var bar = document.getElementById('progressbar');
   createProgressBar = function(bar) {
    var options = {
      start: 0,
      width: bar.getAttribute('data-width'),
      height: bar.getAttribute('data-height'),
      percent: 100,
      lineWidth: bar.getAttribute('data-linewidth')
     },

     canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
     paper = canvas.getContext('2d'),
     span = document.createElement('span'),
     radius = (options.width - options.lineWidth) / 2,
     color = paper.createLinearGradient(0, 0, options.width, 0),

     end = new Date(),
     today = new Date(),

     breakStart = new Date(),
     breakEnd = new Date();


    breakStart.setHours(12, 0, 0);
    breakEnd.setHours(13, 0, 0);


    if(today.getDay() == 5) {
     var full = 480;
     end.setHours(17, 00, 0);
    }
    else {
     var full = 540;
     end.setHours(18, 0, 0);
    }


    span.style.width = bar.style.width = options.width + 'px';
    span.style.height = bar.style.height = options.height + 'px';
    canvas.width = options.width;
    canvas.height = options.height;
    span.style.lineHeight = options.height + 'px';
    span.style.color = 'white';

    color.addColorStop(0, '#ff5349');
    color.addColorStop(0.5, '#ff5349');
    color.addColorStop(1.0, '#ff5349');

    bar.appendChild(span);
    bar.appendChild(canvas);

    function updateTime() {
     var now = new Date(),
      remaining = end - now,

      _second = 1000,
      _minute = _second * 60,
      _hour = _minute * 60,
      _day = _hour * 24,

      hours = Math.floor((remaining % _day) / _hour),
      minutes = Math.floor((remaining % _hour) / _minute),
      seconds = Math.floor((remaining % _minute) / _second),

      current = (full - (hours * 60) - minutes) / full * 100,

      step = 1.5 + (2 * current / 100),


      startb = (breakStart.getHours() * 60 + breakStart.getMinutes()) / full * 100,
      endb = (breakEnd.getHours() * 60 + breakEnd.getMinutes()) / full * 100,

      startBr = 1.5 + (2 * startb / 100),
      endBr = 1.5 + (2 * endb / 100);

     createCircle(options, paper, radius, color, Math.PI * 1.5, Math.PI * step);
     createBreak(options, paper, radius, color, Math.PI * startBr, Math.PI * endBr);
    };

    updateTime();
   },

   createCircle = function(options, paper, radius, color, start, end) {
    paper.clearRect(
     options.width / 2 - radius - options.lineWidth,
     options.height / 2 - radius - options.lineWidth,
     radius * 2 + (options.lineWidth * 2),
     radius * 2 + (options.lineWidth * 2)
    );

    paper.beginPath();
    paper.arc(options.width / 2, options.height / 2, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    paper.strokeStyle = 'white';
    paper.lineCap = 'butt';
    paper.lineWidth = options.lineWidth;
    paper.stroke();
    paper.closePath();
   },

   createBreak = function(options, paper, radius, color, start, end) {
    paper.beginPath();
    paper.arc(options.width / 2, options.height / 2, 171, start, end, false);
    paper.strokeStyle = 'orange';
    paper.lineCap = 'butt';
    paper.lineWidth = 19;
    paper.stroke();
    paper.closePath();
   };
  createProgressBar(bar);
```

```css
body {
   background-color: #333;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: 'sans serif', Verdana, Tahoma, Helvetica;
  }

  canvas {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
  }

  #progressbar {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -180px;
   margin-left: -180px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="progressbar" data-width="360" data-height="360" data-linewidth="16"></div>
```

I can post some screenshots if necessary to make it clear what I mean

Comment: You wish us to debug your code? Why you can't do that?

Comment: spent 2 days - can't find out what's wrong